# Moving file from one directory to another after rename

Tags: linux, shell, unix, mv

I am trying to move files from one directory to another but encounter some errors while doing so using shell script my shell to move files is --

```
cd data
curr=`pwd`
echo $curr
bad_file=`find . -type f -not -name 'dhcp_map_*.csv' -a -type f -not -name 'cmts_map_*csv' -a -type f -not -name 'cmts_dhcp_link_map_*.csv'`

echo $?
#if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
BAD_FILE_CMTS=$(basename "$bad_file")

echo "Bad File Found for CMTS Please check bad folder"

mv $BAD_FILE ../bad/$BAD_FILE_CMTS.bad
#fi

cd ..
```

My main directory structure is like

```
drwxr-xr-x  bad
drwxr-xr-x  data
drwxr-xr-x  done
drwxr-xr-x  log
-rwxr-xr-x  file_chk_1.sh
```

There are more files but these are suffiecient for this problem !

Now in DATA directory there are 3 files

```
-rw-rw-r--  cmts_dhcp_link_map_20160303_1.csv
-rw-rw-r--  cmtsmap_20160303_1.csv
-rw-rw-r--  dhcp_map_20160303_1.csv
```

data could be anything inside these files..

So now as we can see that the file CMTSMAP_20160303_1.CSV has wrong name as it should be like CMTS_MAP_20160303_1.CSV as this is what i am checking in the FIND command.

But when i run this shell it gives me error --

```
/home/vmsow03qa/domains/vm/tools/New_topology_data_load/data
0
Bad File Found for CMTS Please check bad folder
mv: missing destination file operand after `/bad/cmtsmap_20160303_1.csv.bad'
Try `mv --help' for more information.
```

I am unable to figure out what wrong i am doing here also this shell script always print me the message in ECHO "Bad File Found for CMTS Please check bad folder" WHEN THEN THERE ARE FILES WITH CORRECT NAME.

i run this script before it was working fine now my QA team said it is giving me this error :(

Please look into it !

To print message i doint like this

```
cd data
curr=`pwd`
echo $curr
bad_file=`find . -type f -not -name 'dhcp_map_*.csv' -a -type f -not -name 'cmts_map_*csv' -a -type f -not -name 'cmts_dhcp_link_map_*.csv'`

echo $?
BAD_FILE_CMTS=$(basename "$bad_file")

mv $BAD_FILE ../bad/$BAD_FILE_CMTS.bad
if [ -f `ls ./../bad/$bad_file.bad` ];
then
   echo "bad file exist please check"
fi
cd ..
```

But it always print the message in ECHO if there is file in bad folder or not !!

I think i am not doing it properly :(

Comment: `$BAD_FILE` is empty so `../bad/$BAD_FILE_CMTS.bad` is considered as the source file for `mv` command.

Comment: yes i change it to mv $bad_file ../bad/$BAD_FILE_CMTS.bad and its working now i need to print the message if any file is present in bad folder for that we can if[ -f `ls $BAD_FILE_CMTS.bad`]; then echo 'bad file present" fi will work ?